# PHPExcel - How can i read the Excel sheet row by row

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can i read Excel worksheet row by row using PHPExcel? I have a sheet contains more than 100000 rows, but i want to read only 500 rows.

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $sheetData->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheetData->getHighestColumn(); 
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); 

echo '<table>';
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    echo '<tr>';

    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
    echo '<td>' . $sheetData->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only want to ***read*** 500 rows, then only ***load*** 500 rows using a read filter:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example2.xls';


/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */
class myReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    private $_startRow = 0;

    private $_endRow = 0;

    /**  Set the list of rows that we want to read  */
    public function setRows($startRow, $chunksize) {
        $this->_startRow    = $startRow;
        $this->_endRow      = $startRow + $chunkSize;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        //  Only read the heading row, and the rows that are configured in $this->_startRow and $this->_endRow
        if (($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);


/**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
$chunkSize = 500;
/**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
$chunkFilter = new myReadFilter();

/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter that we've Instantiated  **/
$objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);

/**  Tell the Read Filter, the limits on which rows we want to read this iteration  **/
$chunkFilter->setRows(1,500);
/**  Load only the rows that match our filter from $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

See the `PHPExcel User Documentation - Reading Spreadsheet Files` document in `/Documentation` for more details on Read Filters

Comment: Thanks, I found that doc here https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md

Answer (score 8):

You can load 500 rows or even setting start index by setting parameters directly to the getRowIterator function.

```
$path = "Your File Path HERE";
$fileObj = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( $path );
$sheetObj = $fileObj->getActiveSheet();
$startFrom = 50; //default value is 1
$limit = 550; //default value is null
foreach( $sheetObj->getRowIterator($startFrom, $limit) as $row ){
    foreach( $row->getCellIterator() as $cell ){
        $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, only applies to PHPExcel >= 1.8.1

Answer (score 3):

This loops through all rows and columns and assigns the cell value to  $cellValue. If the $i is greater than 500, it breaks out the loop

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();


$i = 0;
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    if ($i > 500) break;
    $i++;

    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
        $cellValue = trim($cell->getCalculatedValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this. but in this case the variable  $objWorksheet stores the entire excel data. In case of large data, it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work, reading? Or loading the spreadsheet to begin with? Post some code that you've already typed.

Comment: I have already read around 5000 rows of excelsheet. but While handling larger file upto 1lakh row, the page doesn't load.

Comment: I suggest you see Mark Baker's answer then and use a read filter to ease the load.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once "/PATH TO PHP EXCEL FOLDER/PHPExcel.php"; 
$inputFileName = $_FILES['FILENAME'];
$objTpl = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('./PATH TO UPLOAD FOLDER/' . $inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
array_shift($sheetData);
$i=0;
$test_array = array();
foreach($sheetData as $key=>$val){
    if($i < 500)
        $test_array[$i] = $val;
    $i++;   
}
```