# PHPExcel lib error when exporting large data

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am getting the below error when exporting large data into excel.

Setting the `memory_limit` variable in the script solves the problem, but that is not the proper solution.

Has anybody faced this kind of problem and solved it? Please help me to solve this too.

Error message:

> E_ERROR: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

Stack trace:

> …c/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/CachedObjectStorage/CacheBase.php (173)
>   …c/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/CachedObjectStorage/CacheBase.php (205)
>   …c/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/CachedObjectStorage/CacheBase.php (264)
>   …/goget.com.au/www/src/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php (1045)
>   …goget.com.au/www/src/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/CSV.php (128)
>   ….au/www/src/vendor/fleetcutter/components/src/Helper/ExcelCSVWriterWrapper.php (77)

Thanks
Amit

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25056427/5517143) will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Have you read the PHPExcel documentation..... like the bit about [using cell caching to reduce memory usage](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md)?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes i read it earlier, but it didnt worked out for me.

Comment: So what methods did you actually try? Simply saying "didn't work for me" tells me nothing.

Comment: PHPExcel is constrained by PHP memory Limits... using cell caching can reduce the required memory for the script and the data but can't eliminate  the need for memory entirely.... Are you simply trying to create a CSV file, or have you loaded another spreadsheet file? Do you have any large arrays in memory? What framework are you using?

Comment: @MarkBaker i am just generating csv file, no new spreadsheet

Comment: If all you're doing is generating a CSV file, then PHPExcel is heavy overkill..... just use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function

Comment: @MarkBaker Let me try to do that, Thanks